# Closing the Softkeyboard on iOS via Adobe AIR

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, mobile, air, android-softkeyboard

... any way to do this?

I'm working on a game project where iPads are displayed in public and players can enter their names and email into a score submit form. However if the device is left unattended for 120 seconds after that it goes automatically back to the title screen. The problem is that if this happens while the softkeyboard is still open, it will not be closed if the timeout happens and the textfield and keyboard are still displayed afterwards (until somebody closes it manually). Needless to say that this is very bad. Haven't found any API on this. Maybe there's a workaround? Setting focus to something else seems not to cut it.

Answer (score 5):

Figured it out! Setting focus to null does the trick!